# Author and title of fantasy book with ka spirit, energy binder general, orphan artist, barrier wall of shelter, and warring tribes

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the author and title of a book with 3 types of magic:

- ka spirit (lizard like)
- leylines energy bindings (life, death, shelter, entropy, far sight?, usually people only have one power, it's special to have more)
- Animal spirits of tribes beyond wall. There's also women's magic.

Some of the characters include: a female general; an orphan artist with binding and ka; and a tribe spirit animal shaman.

Other details include a giant wall for shelter separates tribes from settlers/city folk.

Comment: Hello Duke, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. For the most chances of getting an answer, it's best to ad as many details as possible. For instance, where did you read it - what country? At a small bookstore or a large library? What language did you read it in? Are there any plot details that you can add? What does 'women's magic' mean? Do you have any details about the cover? Anything at all about the author (e.g. man or woman)? See also the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), as well as the [tour] and [ask]. Welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks @mithrandir I obviously did not delve deep enough into guidelines, I was just hitting keywords... Next time :) I stared at my shelves again and found it: soul of the world by David Mealing

Comment: Great that you found it! Could you please now add that as an answer to the question, under this comment thread? After a day or so you'll also be able to accept your own answer by clicking on the gray checkmark on the left. :)